# How could the birds survive outside in the open?

Tags: greenland

In the end of the movie *Greenland*, they open the blast doors after 9 months and soon enough, they hear birds tweeting.

We see how devastating it was outside. There is no chance birds could survive such a big shockwave, the ash falling from the sky, and the heat.

Is there an explanation to that mess?

Comment: Maybe the birds were indoors when the cataclysm happened.

Comment: Just remember: birds have survived every major cataclysm for the last fifty or sixty million years.

Comment: There's no help from the script. In the original version (before Hollywood got their sticky fingers on it), it ends with the impact and the flashbacks to normal life.

Answer (score 3):

As we can see from the various long-shots of cities, the damage is very extensive but not total.

[image: Sidney Opera in a wasteland]

Buildings still stand relatively unscathed and there are plenty of places that roosting birds could have been hiding where they wouldn't have been killed by the initial blast or the subsequent fallout. There doesn't seem to be much by way of 'nuclear winter' aside from a reddened sky so it's pretty realistic for the birds to have either survived in-situ on the island or migrated back to Greenland from Europe or Africa.

---

Birds have, of course, survived other cataclysms in the past so it really should be no surprise that they also survived this one.

Comment: The doors didn't shur just for a few hours. In the BG the radio transmission said it's been 9 months since the blast doors were closed

Comment: @GirishKulkarni - In that case, their costumier and continuity department need firing.

Comment: when they finally ran into the bunker, they didn't have any bag with them. So could be possible that they were wearing the same clothes they came in with.

Comment: @GirishKulkarni - lol. And their hair is identical, as is his beard and the kid hasn't aged, etc